# Confusion in Rx Java Android

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java

Im new to rx and have some lines of code that confuse me:

```
Observable.just(1,2,3,4,5,6)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe { value ->
            Log.i("TEST", "$value")
        }
        .dispose()
```

it will not log the result but when i comment out subscribeOn () and observeOn() or dispose() then it works perfectly, like this:

```
Observable.just(1,2,3,4,5,6)
        .subscribe { value ->
            Log.i("TEST", "$value")
        }
        .dispose()
```

or

```
Observable.just(1,2,3,4,5,6)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe { value ->
            Log.i("TEST", "$value")
        }
```

Can someone explain what happen inside this chain

Comment: `subscribeOn` and `observeOn` introduce asynchrony and with it a time window where the events don't flow yet and thus `dispose` can stop it from happening. Without asynchrony, the events flow right away before you get back the control hence `dispose` is too late by then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` this essentially means that `Observable` will operate on io thread, which will require a thread switch causing some delay.
by the time it happens you have already called the `dispose()` method which disposes the `Observable` hence you don't receive any output.

On the other hand if you remove

```
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
```

This means `Observable` will operate on the calling thread so no thread switch is required, hence you receive complete output before `dispose()` method call can be executed.

If you only remove `dispose()` then nothing is stopping the `Observable` from emitting its contents even though its executing on `io`

Answer (score -1):

- **Observable.just(1,2,3,4,5,6)** -> The Just operator converts an items into an Observable that emits these items.
- **subscribeOn()** -> operator tells the source Observable which thread to emit and push items on all the way down to Observer
- **observeOn()** -> it will switch and pass emissions using that Scheduler for the remaining (downstream) operations
- **subscribe()** -> operator returns Disposable object. You should assign this object to  variable or to CompositeDisposable object. All disposables should be dispose (using **dispose()** method) while your Activity or Fragment ends life to avoid memory leak.

More you can find here:
https://proandroiddev.com/understanding-rxjava-subscribeon-and-observeon-744b0c6a41ea

http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators.html#creating

You can also check Kotlin Coroutines as an alternative to RxJava